# Libgdx JSON custom serialization of Array<Vector2>

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, libgdx

I'm trying to write a custom JSON serializer that can read in an array of floats as the coordinates for Vector2 objects. Suppose I have an array in my class called:

```
Array<Vector2> splinePoints;
```

I would like to be able to read and write a JSON file formatted like:

```
splinePoints: [0,0, 1,1, 2,2]
```

Each pair of floats is read as the x and y coordinates of a Vector2 object. This format allows me to copy and paste spline points generated by Inkscape with minimal editing. Also, this is more compact than the form which would work with the default serializer:

```
splinePoints: [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2}]
```

So far, I've tried this code (which is probably very wrong):

```
public class PointsHolder {
    public Array<Vector2> splinePoints = new Array<Vector2>();
}

Json json = new Json();
json.setSerializer(PointsHolder.class, new Json.Serializer<PointsHolder>() {
    public void write(Json json, PointsHolder pointsHolder, Class knownType) {
        json.writeArrayStart();
        for(Vector2 vector2: pointsHolder.splinePoints) {
            json.writeValue(vector2.x);
            json.writeValue(vector2.y);
        }
        json.writeArrayEnd();
    }

    public PointsHolder read(Json json, JsonValue jsonData, Class type) {
        PointsHolder pointsHolder = new PointsHolder();
        for (JsonValue child = jsonData.child; child != null; child = child.next) {
            Vector2 vector2 = new Vector2();
            vector2.x = jsonData.child.asFloat();
            vector2.y = jsonData.child.next.asFloat();
            pointsHolder.splinePoints.add(vector2);
        }

        return pointsHolder;
    }
});
```

When run, I get an exception saying it's unable to convert value to required type. Even after reading the tutorials and going through the source code, I'm having trouble understanding how the JSON serializer even works. What does JsonValue jsonData refer to when reading an array? What is the third argument "Class" used for in the read and write methods? Do I need to write a serializer for Array.class instead of Vector2.class, although I would still like to use the default serializer for arrays that aren't of type Vector2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `read()` method. You use `jsonData.child` inside loop that is always the first element. Try this instead:

```
public PointsHolder read(Json json, JsonValue jsonData, Class type) {
    PointsHolder pointsHolder = new PointsHolder();
    for (JsonValue child = jsonData.child; child != null; child = child.next.next) {
        Vector2 vector2 = new Vector2();
        vector2.x = child.asFloat();
        vector2.y = child.next.asFloat();
        pointsHolder.splinePoints.add(vector2);
    }

    return pointsHolder;
}
```

I tested this code with the latest release and it works.

UPDATE: I've tested code with the string `[0,0, 1,1, 2,2]`. If you want to deserialize something like

```
{
  splinePoints: [0,0, 1,1, 2,2]
}
```

you have to wrap your PointsHolder with new class. Something like:

```
public class PointsHolderWrapper
{
    public PointsHolder splinePoints;
}
```

Comment: Oh, good catch, but I'm still getting the exception that it's unable to convert to the required type. Could you post your class and json file you tested it with? I'm probably just making some stupid mistake...

Comment: Turns out I was making a very stupid mistake. I had a factory method that set the serializer, but never called it in my main >_<, so the custom serializer was never set. No wonder whatever I tried didn't work, haha. I tried it without the PointsHolderWrapper class and it works great. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that you are doing this at the wrong level.

To do what you want to do your serialisation code should go in the class that contains the splinePoints array.

As you have it your writer would produce

```
splinePoints: [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
```

Have a look here at our [open source libGdx game](https://github.com/MapleScotDevelopment/LoggerBill)

specifically at the Profile class which does full serialisation and at the AchievementManager and LeaderboardManager classes which do reading from a hand created file.

You probably want to do something like

```
json.writeArrayStart();
for(Vector2 v : splinePoints) {
    json.writeValue(v.x);
    json.writeValue(v.y);
}
json.writeArrayEnd();
```

Comment: I see that your readers are manually parsing the files. I was trying to use the Json.fromJson(Class type, FileHandle file) method instead, but maybe it's not possible with the formatting method I want. Is it possible to write a custom deserializer for Array<Vector2> (instead of just Vector2), so that I don't have to copy and paste a manual parser in every class that I want to be able to parse Array<Vector2> in this manner?

Comment: Take another look at the Profile class. It implements the Json.Serializable interface.
You probably want to do that in your container class.

Comment: I wanted to be able to use reflection to read in the rest of the fields. If I used the Json.Serializable interface, wouldn't that require me to manually read and write everything (which is what your Profile class does)? Doing it your way does work nicely, but I was just wondering how to use Json.serializer instead (not that it's vital, but just out of curiosity).

Comment: Yeah I wanted to do that too until I realised the proguard was changing all the names of the fields. Not using reflection also makes things easier with GWT.

Answer (score 0):

This is serialization to json array:

```
class PointsHolder {
Array<Vector2> splinePoints;

// some setters/getters
}

// in your code instead of field/variable:
Array<Vector2> splinePoints;

// use:
PointsHolder splinePointsHolder;
```

Then add some items to splinePointsHolder and serialize it. Serializator should create json array, and add into it all items from splinePoints list (if serialization defined for Vector2). Also maybe you need use supported list/array (if Array is not supported by json serializator).

Comment: I edited my post to use your PointsHolder class. From the looks of it, it should work... but I'm still getting the exception that it can't convert to the required type when trying to read the json file (even when using ArrayList instead). I think I'm doing something wrong with the setSerializer method.